# How to get the buffering percent updates withExoPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

With Mediaplayer, there is a callback method:

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

Is there an equivalent interface with ExoPlayer ?

Comment: Or at least a method like :
`public void onBufferingEnd(ExoPlayer mp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is method exposed by Exoplayer-
public int getBufferedPercentage();

You can schedule something to check if the buffered percentage has changed and act accordingly.

Comment: Any luck on this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837803/how-to-prevent-the-exoplayer-from-reloading-in-case-of-seek-backward? @wholegrain

Answer (score 0):

```
bufferbar.setProgress(exoPlayer.getBufferedPercentage());
```

Comment: please, do not post code-only answers, explain what you did and why

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.