# How to prevent the exoplayer from reloading in case of seek backward?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I am using exoplayer to play mp3 tracks. All good. If the track is completely buffered then in case of seek forward it does not reload as expected. However, in case of seek backward it reloads.
How do i prevent that?
Is it a bug in exo?

Comment: Hey I was just looking into this issue, it is not a bug, exoplayer's buffer clears previous data to free space for new data https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/978.
Did you do any custom implementation to 'fix' this?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but you can use a library that acts as a proxy between ExoPlayer and the video URL like [AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache). It downloads the video to disk and supplies ExoPlayer with the local file URL so re-buffering is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old question and OP might have found the solution. But for anyone looking for answer to this question, we can specify `backBufferDurationMs` in `LoadControl` and use it keep previous data buffered.

```
            val audioOnlyRenderersFactory = AudioUtil.buildAudioRenderersFactory(this)
        val dataSource = AudioUtil.getMediaSourceFactory(this)
        val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBackBuffer(/* backBufferDurationMs= */ 1000 * 60 * 60, true) //for retaining previously loaded one hour data in buffer
            .build()

        val audioAttributes: AudioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(C.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build()
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this, audioOnlyRenderersFactory)
            .setMediaSourceFactory(dataSource)
            .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
            .setLoadControl(loadControl)
            .build()
```