# Exoplayer buffering on full buffer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am developing an application that plays mp4 videos using ExoPlayer.
I have managed to set it up and play some videos, but there is something I don't quite understand.
When the video is fully buffered and I seek forward, the player enters in state BUFFERING and takes some (very short) time to resume playing. What is that time for in a full buffer?? I know that exoplayer does not buffer previous frames, but why is it also rebuffering when going forward?
I have tracked that delay down to "doSomeWork()" method on the TrackRenderers, but still I have no idea how to 'fix' it.
I am currently using the code on ExoPlayer's demo and the ExtractorRendererBuilder for the videos.

Anyone else encountered that situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I've got this problem too, but apparently the asker of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837803/how-to-prevent-the-exoplayer-from-reloading-in-case-of-seek-backward doesn't.... :/

Answer (score 1):

The "BUFFERING" is primarily for two reasons.

1. if the player can seek into a frame in memory, then it does a linear search to find the key-frame and jumps to it. the linear search takes a little while, depending on the number of frames in memory
2. if the frame is not in memory, then exoplayer has to download the frames to memory from network/disk. That obviously takes longer.